# rtl css direction property not working in IE9

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js

In CSS, I specify:

```
#label{
  font-size: 11px;
  fill: black;
  direction: rtl;
  font-weight:bold;
}
```

Then, in my script, I write:

```
squares.append("text").attr("id", "label").text("");
squares.select("#label").attr("x", 0).attr("y", 0).text("Hello");
```

In Chrome, the texts grows from right to left, and hence works as I want it to. But in IE9, it seems to be ignoring the rtl direction property, even if I go:

```
squares.select("#label").attr("x", 0).attr("y", 0).text("Hello").style("direction", "rtl");
```

Any help on making this also work in IE9 would be great!

Comment: can you provide a code or jsfiddle link?

Comment: I specified the code above

Comment: also, squares is a "g" element appended to an svg.